# Как вывести один товар WooCommerce по слагу?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите, как вывести один товар по его слагу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала получаете id поста по его слагу

```
$post = get_page_by_path( 'the_slug', OBJECT, 'product' ) );
```

Затем получаете товар по его id

```
if ( $post ) {
    $product = wc_get_product( $post );
}
```

И выводите его.